# ConcurrentTestRunner Maven - Test Success Not Reported

Tags: maven, junit, concurrency

I'm reading through [ConcurrentTestRunner](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/junit/junit-multithreaded-test-example/) and implemented my first test class with 4 test cases. I'm building with Maven through IJ & as specified in that article I included this dependency in the POM.xml:

```
<!-- Concurrent JUnit -->
 <dependency>
      <groupId>com.vmlens</groupId>
      <artifactId>concurrent-junit</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

If I break them, my tests report *failure* correctly, but when they pass, Maven/IJ doesn't pick up that fact, claiming that 0 tests were run:

> [INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed:
>   0.002 s

The total number of tests is also short by 4, as it is 75 and should be 79:

> [INFO] Tests run: 75, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

Answer (score 0):

It was an old bug. Changed the version number to 1.0.2 and it now works. Here's the POM element:

```
<!-- Concurrent JUnit -->
 <dependency>
      <groupId>com.vmlens</groupId>
      <artifactId>concurrent-junit</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.2</version>
 </dependency>
```